# How to record multitrack indefinitely

Tags: sound, files, alsa, audio-recording

I can't seem to get past ~10.5 minutes with 18 tracks without dropping samples across a file-split.  I have this script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Dedicated SATA SSD for Recording
REC_DRIVE=/dev/sda
REC_PATH=/home/audiohub/Recordings
mount -t ext4 $REC_DRIVE "$REC_PATH"

# Start recording
#arecord --device=hw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0 --channels=18 --file-type=wav --format=S32_LE --rate=48000 --buffer-time=20000000 --max-file-time 300 "$REC_PATH/all_tracks.wav" &
#arecord --device=hw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0 --channels=18 --file-type=wav --format=S32_LE --rate=48000 --buffer-time=20000000 --separate-channels "$REC_PATH/track.wav" &
arecord --device=hw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0 --channels=18 --file-type=raw --format=S32_LE --rate=48000 --buffer-time=20000000 "$REC_PATH/all_tracks.raw" &
ARECORD_PID=$!

# Force a filesystem sync every 1 second to keep the buffer small enough to write without missing samples
COUNT=1
while kill -0 "$ARECORD_PID" > /dev/null 2>&1
do
    sleep 1
    echo sync $COUNT
    sync
    COUNT=$(($COUNT+1))
done
echo Recording has ended.
```

The first option in that script (commented out) creates a bunch of 5-minute, 18-track WAV files that I can then rearrange with `SoX` into a bunch of full-length, single-track WAV files.  This is presently the only way I know to capture an entire show in multitrack, but the final WAV files have a "pop" every 5 minutes like `arecord` is dropping samples during the file split.

The second option (also commented out) fails immediately, but does create a `track.wav0` file with zero size.

The third option (not commented out) runs until the `all_tracks.raw` file reaches exactly 2.0GiB and then fails with the following output in the logfile:

```
Recording raw data '/home/audiohub/Recordings/all_tracks.raw' : Signed 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Channels 18
sync 1
sync 2
sync 3
sync 4
sync 5
...
sync 526
sync 527
sync 528
sync 529
sync 530
/home/audiohub/Recordings/all_tracks.raw: No such file or directory
sync 531
Recording has ended.
```

I can then split the `all_tracks.raw` file with `SoX` into 18 single-track WAV files and play them correctly in Audacity, so I know it's capturing okay...at least for the first ~10.5 minutes.

Is there a way to capture an entire show's worth (at least 4 hours) of 18-track audio without dropping anything?

Comment: Are you using 64-bit userspace? Try `arecord > output.raw`.

Comment: @CL. You mean like `arecord --device=hw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0 --channels=18 --file-type=raw --format=S32_LE --rate=48000 --buffer-time=20000000 > "$REC_PATH/all_tracks.raw" &`?  (simply inserting a `>` in the original command with all the options still there)

Comment: Yes, just record to stdout instead of a file.

Comment: @CL. Okay, that's easy enough to try.  As for the userspace, I'm not entirely sure what the answer is except that `arecord` runs on an Allwinner A20 CPU (Banana Pi Pro), and whatever it comes up with is transferred to a known 64-bit HP netbook that has `SoX` installed for post-processing.

Comment: The Cortex A7 is a 32-bit CPU.

Answer (score 1):

@CL.'s comment was the solution: pipe the audio through stdout and let the operating system handle the file.

[The full write-up is here](https://forum.music-group.com/showthread.php?13813-18-track-Recorder-Remote-Jukebox-Solo-Talkback-Streaming), but the answer to this particular problem is:

```
arecord --device=hw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0 --channels=18 --file-type=raw --format=S32_LE --rate=48000 --buffer-time=20000000 > "$REC_FILE" 2> >(ts -s >&2) &
```

The `2> >(ts -s >&2)` at the end pipes `arecord`'s stderr to `ts`'s stdin, and `ts`'s stdout to the script's stderr.  The calling script pipes this script's stderr to a logfile.

`ts` adds a timestamp to each line of its stdin and prints the result to its stdout.  So when I look at the logfile, I can see if there were any problems, and if there were, where to look for glitches/pops in the multi-hour multi-track recording.

---

Then to convert the raw file to a set of full-length mono WAV's:

```
TRACKS=18
CHANNEL=$TRACKS
while [ $CHANNEL -ge 1 ]
do
  FILENAME=track$CHANNEL.wav
  sox --type raw --bits 32 --channels $TRACKS --encoding signed-integer --rate 48000 --endian little all_tracks.raw $FILENAME remix $CHANNEL
  CHANNEL=`expr $CHANNEL - 1`
done
```

You might want to add some `echo`s in there to report progress.  This tends to take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the wav file format, which is essentially limited to a 2GB file size.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV and https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,32422.0.html

Some programs will let you record to 4GB (I use Ardour, and Audacity also does this I believe) to record to alternate formats when I need longer recording times.

Comment: Wow, I had completely forgotten about this.  CL.'s comment to pipe through stdout instead of directly to file was the solution.  Basically moves the 2GB problem from `arecord` to the operating system.  So I now produce a single RAW file in the 10's of GB range for each show that I can then split with `SoX` into a collection of full-length, mono WAV's.  Audacity is okay with a 2.5GB WAV, but I haven't tried my system yet with theoretically >4GB per track.  I'm sure I could record that long (5.3 hours), but converting might be interesting.

Comment: If I remember right, I think there was too much going on at the time to remember to come back and report success, so that @CL. could make his comment into an answer.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @AaronD I'm somewhat interested in this topic, as I use an XR18 as well.  What does your entire command look like to record a session?

Comment: Better still, here's the full write-up with source code and everything: https://forum.music-group.com/showthread.php?13813-18-track-Recorder-Remote-Jukebox-Solo-Talkback-Streaming

Comment: @AaronD That looks like a really neat project.  I can see how I would use 'arecord' to simplify my son's band doing garage recordings, but 'SoX' mystifies me!  I need only 6 channels (3-8) of the output for them - can you give me some clues?

Comment: @AaronD Found your convert from raw script - It's a shame there does not seem to be an easy way to use SoX to get all channels independently, as you could pipe from arecord to sox....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69524/discussion-between-aarond-and-charles-green).

Comment: @Aaron's I'm away from my computer right now, but will attempt to try to chat with you a little later